# Getting week # from date in SQL with strange company rules

Tags: sql, db2-luw

I'm attempting to convert dates to week numbers in SQL. I need to implement it in DB2 and Redshift queried via DBeaver and SAS. None of the weekpart functions follow our rules, and we're not allowed to create a lookup table in any of the databases, so the team has been using massive case statements as a workaround (52 when statements / year).

I've been trying to come up with a solution other than many different case statements. The company has a particular rule which is proving difficult to implement. First, here are the easy rules to write:

1. weeks start on Friday
2. weeks cap at 52. If there is a week 53, count it as part of week 52.
3. Week 52 always ends on 12/31
4. Week 1 always starts on 1/1

Here's the one I'm struggling with:

5. If there are 3 or fewer days in week 1, include all of week 2 with week 1 and therefor subtract 1 from all future weeks of that year.

I reduced the size of the case statement they use by using yearly case statements and math, but I'm guessing this will take longer to execute, and I still have to write a case statement for each year. Here's some "pseudo code" for what I came up with.

```
case 
  --repeat start here for each year
    when year(date_col) = 2023 then
        case 
            when date_col <= %last_day_of_week_1_2023% then 1
            else min(int(datediff(day, %last_day_of_week_1_2023%, date_col) / 7 + 2),52)
        end
 --repeat end here for each year
```

Is there any way to implement all these rules without a case statement for each year?

Comment: That fifth rule should read, 
If there are 3 or fewer days in week 1....

Comment: Then what happens to week 1 if there are 4 or more days in week 1 (as is week 1 this year according to your rules)? and how many days in week 52 then?

Comment: So, is 4th of January always in week 1? That could be your rule for calculating everything.

Comment: @Atmo This year, week 2 starts on 1/6, and week 52 is 12/22 through 12/31.

Comment: @JamesZ That's it!  I don't know the SQL off the top of my head, but If the weekday of the 1/4/yearpart(date_col) > Thursday then add one day to the weeknum and use min to avoid week 53 and I believe that'll work. I'll try that Monday morning.

Comment: Oh, or if it's a Sunday

Answer (score 0):

If you know which date is the first Friday in the year then it just reduces to a division problem.  You just have to add upper and lower bounds to prevent getting WEEK 0 or 53.

Finding the first Friday is easy in SAS since there is function for that.

```
data test;
  input date :yymmdd.;
  downame=put(date,downame.-l);
  week1=nwkdom(1,6,1,year(date));
  if day(week1)<4 then week1=week1+7;
  raw_week=1+ceil((date-week1)/7);
  week=max(1,min(52,raw_week));
  format date week1 yymmdd10.;
cards;
2014-01-01
2019-12-31
;
```

Result

```
Obs          date     downame          week1    raw_week    week

 1     2014-01-01    Wednesday    2014-01-10        0         1
 2     2019-12-31    Tuesday      2019-01-04       53        52
```

If you want to do it in PROC SQL then use something like

```
max(1,min(52,1+ceil((date -
    case when 3<day(nwkdom(1,6,1,year(date))) then nwkdom(1,6,1,year(date))
         else nwkdom(1,6,1,year(date))+7
    end)/7)
    )) as week
```

Comment: It does need to be in PROC SQL in SAS, but it also needs to either be an implicit or explicit passthrough. I don't think nwkdom would qualify, but I've not checked. 

I didn't know about nwkdom, and will definitely be using elsewhere, so thank you for that!

Comment: In REDSHIFT if you can figure how to get 03JANyyyy from your date you can use NEXT_DAY() function to find the first Friday after that.